# Which JavaScript function is faster

Tags: javascript, html

As I progress to teach myself JavaScript, an aspect comes to mind. Which function is faster and uses less memory of finding id's in an html?

I see this function very often but I've never used it:

```
document.getElementById("abc");
```

I use this everywhere in my Polymer app:

```
document.querySelector('#abc');
```

I hope I have not asked a silly question but few weeks ago I was reading an article and someone mentioned one is faster. Could someone explain if this is true please?

Comment: Measure it and find out.

Comment: no way to tell, as it'd depend on the particular JS engine you're using. You'll have to test it.

Comment: @MarcB how do you test/measure it?

Comment: This is pretty cool worth a peak https://jsperf.com/jquery-selectors-vs-native-api

Comment: you benchmark it. do a bunch of selections and time how long they take, and do enough of them for long enough that random background system "noise" doesn't throw off the results.

Comment: @vikingben actually that's not a jQuery selector, it's the native .querySelector

Comment: @Jack hmm I thought they were all there my bad. Still think it's worth a peek.

Comment: `document.getElementById` seems to be the fastest

Comment: @vikingben the test you linked does not include the case the OP is asking for.

Comment: @dave that link does compare the speed of the two functions mentioned by OP

Comment: https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector

Comment: @hopkins-matt no it doesn't. It doesn't use a querySelector by id

Comment: Marked as duplicate. Where is the original question as I need to know?

Comment: @dave ah. you are correct. overlooked that the test used class.